# Full calendar business hour constrain on day click event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to put in a full calendar in a jspx and I dont want the click to be enabled if the user is clicking outside of business hours. I am able to make it work based on days, but when it comes to the time,I am not sure how to do it. There is a break hour every day during which people cannot book appointments. Is there a way to apply the business hours constrain to day click? This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaDay,list',               

        },
        stick:true,
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        defaultTimedEventDuration:'00:15:00', 

        //removed business hours from day view
        minTime: "08:00:00",
        maxTime: "17:00:00",


        //shows time in 15 min slot
        slotDuration: '00:15:00',
        slotLabelInterval: 15,
        slotLabelFormat: 'h(:mm)a',

        //set business hours
    businessHours:[{            
        dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], // Monday - Friday
        start: '08:00',
        end: '12:00', 
    },
    {
        dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], // Monday - Friday (if adding lunch hours)
        start: '13:00',
        end: '17:00', 
    }],


    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        //alert(view.name);

        if(moment(date).day()==0||moment(date).day()==6)
            alert("Cannot book out of business hours");
        //else if()

        if (date.getHours() <= 18 && date.getHours() >= 9)
            alert("Cannot book out of business hours");

        if(view.name == 'agendaDay')    
        {
        if(moment(date).day()==0||moment(date).day()==6)
            alert("Cannot book out of business hours");
        else
            {
                var today=new Date();
                if(moment(date)>=today)
                {

                    var eventTitle = prompt("Provide Event Title");
                    if (eventTitle) {
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                    title: eventTitle,
                    start: moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'), 
                    stick: true
                    });
                    alert('Appoinment booked on time: '+moment(date).format("hh:mm"));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                alert('Cannot book appoinments in past dates'); 
                }

            }
        }

    },

    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

        alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);


    },

    })

});
```

Comment: That should be check upon the time regarding to UTC time. What if you have a user in another timezone? Yeah... You got the idea. You have to carry the server time as a reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My advice would be not to use "dayClick" to create events (i.e. in your case to book appointments). The way recommended by fullCalendar is to use the "select" callback to capture this kind of user input.

The key advantage of this for your requirement (apart from following the recommended approach) is that you can then set the `selectConstraint` option to correlate with your businessHours, and that will automatically prevent the user from selecting times which fall outside the business hours.

Then the only extra manual validation you need is to check the appointment does not occur in the past. I have amended the code you wrote for that to simplify it and be more reliable, using momentJS's built-in comparison methods.

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    selectable: true,
    defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:15:00',
    minTime: "08:00:00",
    maxTime: "17:00:00",
    slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    slotLabelInterval: 15,
    slotLabelFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,listDay'
    },
    businessHours: [{
      dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // Monday - Friday
      start: '08:00',
      end: '12:00',
    }, {
      dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // Monday - Friday (if adding lunch hours)
      start: '13:00',
      end: '17:00',
    }],
    selectConstraint: "businessHours",
    select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
      if (start.isAfter(moment())) {

        var eventTitle = prompt("Provide Event Title");
        if (eventTitle) {
          $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
            title: eventTitle,
            start: start,
            end: end,
            stick: true
          });
          alert('Appointment booked at: ' + start.format("h(:mm)a"));
        }
      } else {
        alert('Cannot book an appointment in the past');
      }
    },
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
      alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
    }
  });
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/162/ for a working demo.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/ for more details.

N.B. Of course this is only client-side validation. A user can easily bypass this and send a HTTP request to your server with booking information in it, so you always need to re-validate the request when it reaches your server.

Comment: I played with your Fiddle... I would change the condition to `if (start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM") > (moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM")))` to allow appointements "today" too. +1

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette all you're doing there is comparing strings instead of moments. I fail to see what difference that makes, other than string comparison is less "correct" than direct date comparison. You can already create events "today", if it's early enough in the day. Right now (in GMT at least) we've gone past 5pm so inevitably you can't create anything for today, because all the allowed times (as per the business hours) are already in the past.

Comment: Well... On your Fiddle, I can't book an appointment for 1pm. And currently 12:08 here. Okay, that's because I'm in UCT-5... I wonder how to change the timezone then... I will look into Moment docs... ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I wonder if this is a timezone issue. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/#ambiguously-zoned. Hard for me to test since GMT is the same as UTC right now. Try outputting the time values of `start` and `moment()` and see what they say.  I'm not sure TBH, I'll admit to not being very cognisant with all the timezeone stuff, just by pure chance I've never worked on an app which needed to worry about it... All I know is it worked for me when I tested it earlier. I'll re-try it in the morning to be certain.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yep it's Jan 26 07:44 GMT now and I can create events for the rest of 26 Jan quite happily using that calendar. Can you try modifying the fiddle to use `timezone: "local"` or `timezone: "UTC"` or your local timezone, and see if any those help? I'd be interested to know how to make it work universally. Of course, it _could_ be argued that the behaviour you saw was correct - it wouldn't let you add an event because in the UTC/GMT timezone which the calendar was targeting, that time _was_ in the past. So in real-life it wouldn't be possible to schedule an appointment then.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below attribute  :

```
selectConstraint: "businessHours",
```

Comment: As per my answer, this won't achieve anything unless the OP also changes their code to use the "select" callback instead of "dayClick". This is only a partial solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who doesn't want to use selecting:

```
function inBusinessHours(date, businessHours) {
  let dateDay = date.getDay();
  for (var i = 0; i < businessHours.length; i++) {
    // check if date should conform to this dict's start and end times
    if (businessHours[i].daysOfWeek.includes(dateDay)) {
      // toLocaleTimeString with arg it-IT will return 24hr time
      let timeStr = date.toLocaleTimeString('it-IT')

      // if time after or equal to business hour start for day
      if (businessHours[i].startTime <= timeStr) {
        // if time before or equal to business hour end for day
        if (businessHours[i].endTime >= timeStr) {
          return true
        }
      }
      //  if the day matches, but any of the times do not, dont check any more
      //    days and just return false immediately
      return false
    }
  }
  // if date clicked's weekday is not in businessHours at all
  return false;
}
```

I'm using this for clicking on the calendar, passing a Date object created from the click info on dateClick and returning if the check does not pass.

This assumes your business hours are in the user's local time (they should be). If they are not, then the event disabling will be offset by their timezone offset from your business hour timezone offset.